# Two ornaments next to page numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-numbering, page, pgfornament, styles

I would like to place two mirrored ornaments next to each page number. I am using package pgfornaments.

Something like this...

[image: --]

Comment: What have you tried and what is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fancyhdr` package to add a footer to every page that contains the current page number with the `\fancyfoot` command. This command takes effect after specifying `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Within this command you can use `\thepage` to display the current page. The ornament you show on the left is `\pgfornament{2}`, the mirrored version on the right can be obtained with `\reflectbox{\pgfornament{2}}`.

The standard size of the ornaments is quite big, you can make them smaller by specifying `width=1cm` for example.

Then the ornaments need to be raised a bit with `\raisebox` to display them at the same vertical level as the number itself.

The `\fancyfoot` command can be used to set the footer on the left, center and right of the page, in this case just the center is sufficient. This can be specified with the `[C]` optional argument.

MWE (note that the `lipsum` package it just to display some random text to fill the pages, this package and the `\lipsum` command are not needed in your real document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{1.5mm}{\pgfornament[width=1cm]{2}} \thepage\ \raisebox{1.5mm}{\reflectbox{\pgfornament[width=1cm]{2}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Result on page 6:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, its perfect.